# How do I set the RadEditor height proportional to the RadWindow height when using Telerik controls?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad

**Details of the work:**

I am using RadWindow and RadEditor (the version is 2008.3.1314.35) with the editor within the RadWindow. My requirement is to set the height of the RadEditor proportional to (a percentage of) the RadWindow height.

**What I did & the problems faced:**

I have started with the client script in the .aspx page which is being loaded in to the window. In the window.onload I am trying to fetch the RadWindow height and set the height of the editor based on that value, but I can't get the RadWindow height. I have used .get_height() of the RadWindow object and also .getWindowBounds(); but it is throwing script errors.

**So here is my concern:**

1. Is there any property in the RadEditor that would serve my requirement detailed above, i.e. auto size the editor based on the size of the RadWindow?
2. Am I going in the right direction? Are there any alternatives you could suggest? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can have [this sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/editorinradwindow/defaultcs.aspx) for starter and combine it with the [auto-resize telerik window feature](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/autosize/defaultcs.aspx) to avoid any manual coding. Bear in mind that the latter is part of the Q3 2010 telerik release.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.Using the sample, now i am accessing the parent radwindow object in the OnClientLoad event using (window.radWindow;).After that i am fetching the width & height of window using GetWidth(); & GetHeight(); and inturn using setSize() of the editor to give desired sizes.I got tip from Telerik support forums too.